# Auto­mat­i­cal­ly move mouse point­er to default but­ton on dia­log box

Tags: macos, big-sur

Is there a way to auto­mat­i­cal­ly move the cursor to default but­ton on dia­log boxes or confirmation messages?
I've been a windows user for a long time and this function can be easily set in the Control panel.
Am wondering if there's a similar functionality in MacOS Big Sur.

Comment: There is no built-in setting for that behavior. Maybe a _third-party utility_, Google-foo...  http://www.plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/index.html (Apple Magic Mouse and Magic Trackpad are not supported.)

Comment: I tried this for about 2 days, maybe 15 years ago, as it sounded like *'a great idea'*. In practise it is horribly confusing. Never again.

Comment: Wow never noticed that on Windows, that would be horribly distracting. (Having said that a robot API should be available on most systems)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is not.

Fundamental to macOS is the design principle that only the user moves the pointer, which is one's tool to manipulate items in the interface. This approach gives the user full control over the pointer, physically and cognitively. Were it to move unpredictably and unrelated to the movement made by the user, it would result in confusion and cognitive dissonance, such as:

- *where did the pointer go? I was just looking at it and it disappeared*
- *I was about to click on something over here, but when I did so a button on a different part of the screen got clicked*

This is so fundamental in fact, that I can't find a specific reference to it in Apple's documentation. Maybe it is not explicitly discussed since Apple set the standard through its API and it is accepted as a given now after nearly 40 years. The most relevant references I can find are ones like these from *[Inside Macintosh](http://www.weihenstephan.org/%7Emichaste/pagetable/mac/Inside_Macintosh.pdf)* (1985):

> …the user's actions tend to have direct results … The user, not the system, decides what to do next … they would be confused and irritated if they had to learn a completely new interface for each application …
>
> In general, moving the mouse changes nothing except the location, and
> possibly the shape, of the pointer.

So, left implied by Apple's human interface guidelines — and enforced by the API — is that the pointer should only be moved when the user interacts intentionally with the mouse/trackpad/pointing device.

Now, this begs the question, why do you want this behavior?

- If you are a programmer, I would strongly urge avoiding doing this in your applications for the reasons above.
- If you want it for yourself, what is your goal, that you can more easily target the default button in dialog boxes? If so, I would call your attention to the fact that the primary (default) button is given the system's highlight color (by default a blue background) and will respond to a press of the <kbd>Return</kbd> key. Note the examples in Apple's current Human Interface Guidelines at [Dialogs](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/windows-and-views/dialogs/). (Also note that if you have **System Preferences** ▶ **Keyboard** ▶ **Shortcuts** ▶ **Use keyboard navigation…** turned on, you can use <kbd>Tab</kbd> / <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to change what button is selected and <kbd>Space</kbd> to activate it.)

So perhaps you can come to appreciate the predictability of the Mac pointer not jumping around — especially since as a longtime Windows user, it should be comforting to know keyboard shortcuts can be your fastest approach to confirming dialogs.

Comment: I don't know if it's still possible with the current security model, but at least in older versions of OSX, applications could move the mouse pointer through the accessibility API.

Comment: I think this is an opinionated answer. It doesn't answer the question but tries to explain the question is a wrong ask. 
A very simple use case is when my left hand is not on the keyboard (e.g drinking coffee, or resting for a couple of minutes, etc) so I am clicking on buttons and a dialog opens and I have to move my mouse all the way to the dialog buttons, and then return my mouse cursor to the previous or a new location and seconds later another dialog opens and again move your mouse, etc.
For me, this built-in feature in Windows was very useful, and now I wish I could have it on my Mac.

Answer (score 2):

SteerMouse has this function beside others.
https://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/download.php

[image]